# Disable Javascript in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

My iOS app needs to display very basic HTML received from a third party (using `loadHTMLString` with nil as `baseURL`).

Using a `UIWebView` was simple enough, however - I have a security concern since this view can also run Javascript, which is not allowed and also unnecessary for my app.

Is there a way to disable the app from running javascript? If not - does anyone know of a good sanitizing code to remove any malicious stuff (yet keep the regular HTML) from an `NSString`?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to use WKWebView it have the configuration option where you can set

```
javaScriptEnabled = NO;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKPreferences_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKPreferences/javaScriptEnabled

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems awesome, but I want to support iOS 7 as well

Comment: ios 7 - it's only 12% of devices :) https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/